# Duplicate all strings in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, localization

I remember reading somewhere about one of Xcode's features which will cause all strings in your application to appear as double in length, simply by repeating their contents. For example, if a UILabel contains the text `Username:`, it will now contain the text `Username:Username:`. I can't find any reference to this on Google. How can I access this feature in Xcode?

The idea is that it can help you debug localization issues, since some languages have very long strings compared to English.

**Update:** I believe I heard about it in the [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) Auto Layout by Example (232) video.

(Search keywords: NSString, double, debug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: DoubleLocalizedStrings]

Select your target in the Xcode toolbar and go to "Edit Scheme...", add the launch argument `-NSDoubleLocalizedStrings YES` Now all of your text that uses `NSLocalizedString` and its ilk will be doubled.

Comment: More info about setting these arguments can be [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13138933/35690).